# How to redirect outbound requests to external resource to localhost with different ports?

Tags: networking, proxy, firewall, iptables, gitlab

I have GitLab CI multirunner which attempts clone git repo from external URL `mydomain.com:40800` and it gets timeout error (I nothing cant to do with that). I need to redirect `mydomain.com:40800` HTTP requests from this machine (or process) to `localhost:80`. 
I cant realize which solution to use:

- `etc/hosts` - unable to map ports
- `Nginx`'s reverse proxy - is it working with *outbound* http requests?
- `iptables` - after googling I came to a conclusion that it is application level problem, is't it?
- Any other specific proxy server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my case

1. add in `/etc/hosts` alias for external url

   `127.0.0.1       mydomain.com`
2. In `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` setup proxy

   ```
   server {
   listen 40080 default_server;
   listen [::]:40080 default_server;


   root /var/www/html;

   server_name _;

   location / {
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80;
         }
   }
   ```